# Location of Event logs in Windows

Tags: windows-7, forensics

I have found that Windows logs every event such as system login/out, USB connection's history, etc. This all can be viewed in Event viewer.

But my question is **Where on the filesystem are the event log files located on Windows 7?**

Comment: Do you mean "where on the filesystem are the event log files located"?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what it meant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These files are located in the folder `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs` with the extension `.evtx`

Comment: Something unusual most probably relating to the W10 upgrade from Win8.1 ~Apr 2016 placed all the `evtx` log files in _C:\Logs_ with the same date stamp. No such problem with the ones in _C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs_!